# What software can be used to view JSON data from an API in tabular view like SSMS?

Tags: windows, api, sql, json

I've used SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to query data in tabular view from MS SQL Server. In thinking about a SaaS product that does not have direct SQL access, what is an equivalent tool that can be used to quickly get data out of the system and aggregate with similar flexibility (T-Sql). SQL provided endless possibilities, so I am curious what might be out there to work with API based data in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) should have everything that you need including the API perspective.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).